# Connecting .NET Membership and Roles wth Existing Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I find a few topics on this, but they point to too-generic documentation or, for the link that seemed most pertinent so far, don't work.
(I'll refer to all the built-in functionality for membership/roles in .NET as "Membership" here on out.)

Using .NET 4.0 and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and SQL Server 2005.

I'm creating a website where, in order to sign up, you need to be a paying member. I've already created the database that holds all membership info, and I've already created the form where they sign up, as well as the pages where they themselves or site admins can manage their account info. I've also even created a class for authenticating them and checking for permission on pages based on level of access (roles).

I'm hoping for a clear, concise explanation of either of these options:

• Point "Membership" at the place where username/password are stored, disallowing it from auto-creating its own db. (I'll then go back through my site and replace my own custom authentication in the few places I have it with official .NET "Membership".)

• Or still run my own custom authentication, but in that process, say to "Membership", "Hey! User known as "username" and of role "member" is now authenticated. Note that in your own special place, assign them that role, and know what to do with it when I ask you hereafter." Could this be "Forms Authentication API"?

There's more to the account than just username/password/role. I know I can add more fields to accounts created using .NET but I also really don't want to use some randomly created, self-contained, disjointed database just for the sake of handling logins.

I have not yet learned the basics of "Membership", though I'm getting darn close in my process of learning .NET; and I can't spend the time right now making progress on that for personal reasons, but I have to proceed with making this site. I would like to be able to use many of the benefits that come along with .NET security, like being able to exclude users from folders using web.config, etc.

Mostly I'm just seeking assurance it will be possible for me to backpedal after I get some other aspects of the project shored up, but before I make it live, and without having to rewrite half of the membership forms and splitting that data into several databases and figuring out how to use "Membership" for either pieces of it or all of it when a member signs up.
Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are working on is similar to something I am working on here.

We have a custom authentication scripts in ColdFusion and I am creating a second .NET System with Membership login.

The way I went about it was to move all the user/role/profile information into Membership's tables and created an additional tblUserProperties table which holds all other information that the Membership standard tables cannot hold.

I have recoded the ColdFusion queries to point to the new Membership tables.

This way, if a user change password from either system, the logins will work from the other system as well.

I think keeping two systems/tables that do the same thing (authentication) is risky because of the password change reasons. There could be more, but why can't you just simply change your custom code to point to where Membership is pointing? That way you can use Membership provider to its full potential.

Comment: Sounds like simply rearranging what I've made will be the best way to go. Part of my problem is that I never know whether taking the time required to learn a new aspect (of any given program) will be worth it, because I'm always having to figure these things out in the wrong order, by myself, and in the thick of "we want it yesterday" and there's too often some drawback, shortcoming, or wall that I hit, but usually only after I've dedicated significant amounts of time to an avenue.

Comment: These things also frustrate me no end because there's no logical reason, for everything else that's configurable in .NET, for me to not be able to point Membership to a specific place, and say look here, here, and here for the data you need. Ultimately it will help, someday, when I can actually be thoroughly familiar with a given system, and not be working between multiple platforms.

Comment: Membership creates stored procs in the database that it uses. You can edit these procs as long as you maintain data types and column names. Now if you mess up there you won't be able to figure out where the error comes from unless you Refactor the Membership Provider. 

I recommend using Membership as is and just work around it. You will find significant help here if you don't change Membership completely, or use it in its native state.

Comment: I'm starting to assemble a picture of how this can all work. Just need to work out whatever obstacles I'll find along the way, and then it'll be good to go.

Comment: You can contact me anytime if you need assistance.